# How to rename xarray dataArray that is a string?

Tags: python, python-xarray, hdf

I am using a large HDF4 dataset with ~130 data variables. The name of each data variable is a string, and I would like to rename them to be 1 word (e.g. 'Surface pressure' to 'Surface_pressure'. Since they are a string, I am unable to use most functions, such as dataArray.where. I can only access each variable using dataset['dataArray_1'], and this is less than ideal. I would like to be able to use dataset.dataArray.

I have tried using dataArray.rename but am not having any luck. I have copy and pasted the error below.

```
In: data=('test.h4')
    DS=xr.open_dataset(data)

In: DS['Surface pressure']

Out: <xarray.DataArray 'Surface pressure' (Footprints: 25590)>
array([1006.09015, 1006.09015, 1006.09015, ...,  997.5478 ,  997.5478 ,
        997.5478 ], dtype=float32)
Dimensions without coordinates: Footprints
Attributes:
    units:        hectoPascal
    format:       F18.9
    valid_range:  [   0. 1100.]

In: DS.rename({'Surface pressure':'Surface_pressure'})

In: DS.Surface_pressure

Out: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-6b1398c52ba1> in <module>
----> 1 DS.Surface_pressure

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    177                     return source[name]
    178         raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
--> 179                              (type(self).__name__, name))
    180 
    181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'Surface_pressure'
```

I expect to see the the xarray.DataArray insead of an error and I'm not sure what else to try next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xarray's `rename()` returns a *new* Dataset object rather than modifying the an existing inplace. So getting it to do what you want should be as simple as overriding the `DS` variable, e.g.,

```
DS = DS.rename({'Surface pressure':'Surface_pressure'})
```

Some simple string manipulation in Python should make it straightforward to rename all the existing variables into your desired form, e.g.,

```
name_map = {k: k.replace(' ', '_').lower() for k in DS}
DS = DS.rename(name_map)
```